# Close Chromewebdriver when user close tab in Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

When using **Selenium** to create a Chrome app, **chromedriver.exe** still in background when user close the tab manually. Is there any way to fix this?

I don't want to use `driver.quit()` in my code, because user need to do something in this chrome app.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--app=https://www.jianshu.com/sign_in')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(".\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"session_email_or_mobile_number\"]').send_keys('aaaa')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"session_password\"]').send_keys('bbbbbbbbbb')
```

[image]

Comment: You mean the chromedriver.exe instance not closing when you close the chrome instance closed manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we don't have a direct solution to close the `chromedriver.exe` when user manually close the chrome instance launched by selenium. Alternatively you can save the below command as bat and then double click each time you close the `chrome` tab manually.

```
taskkill /IM  chromedriver.exe /F
```

Comment: The command may not be useful because it will close all chromedriver.exe which are used by other selenium programs. I am thinking can I have only one chromedriver.exe running in background, selenium programs connect to it other than launch a new chromedrive.exe.

Comment: Other option is you can use `driver.service.process.pid` to get the PID and update the bat file right after the browser is launched. So now, the bat file will close the latest chromedriver.exe instance. Just sharing thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--app=https://www.jianshu.com/sign_in')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(".\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id=\"session_email_or_mobile_number\"]').send_keys('aaaa')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=\"session_password\"]').send_keys('bbbbbbbbbb')

driver.close()
```

///just add driver.close() to close the chrome browser after the test

Comment: I have tried this and `driver.quit()`, nothing works :(. If you open task manager, `chromedriver.exe` is still there. Also, I can't directly call `driver.close()` in my code, it will close opened tabs immediately while I need to do some work on this web page.