# How to handle user closing in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I made a selenium program in c# which I call an instance of the class from a winform class. The issue I am having is if the user quits their chrome browser while selenium is running the program freezes for a second. I am assuming this is due to having to quit the webdriver. Is there anyway around this, other than a try, catch? I was referring to [Close Chromewebdriver when user close tab in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60611006/16295530), but I do can't seem to understand the answer.

```
   public class BlizzGenMain
    {

        public static ChromeOptions options;
        public static IWebDriver driver;
        public static Proxy proxy;
        public static WebDriverWait wait;
        public static String orderID;
        public static String phoneNum;
        public static String code;
        public static String email;
        public static String password;
        public static String simKey;

        public BlizzGenMain(String simAPI, String pass)
        {
            var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            orderID = "";
            phoneNum = "";
            email = "";
            code = "";
            simKey = simAPI;
            password = pass;
            options = new ChromeOptions();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
            proxy = new Proxy();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            


        }

        static void openChrome()
        {  
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://account.battle.net/creation/flow/creation-full");
        }
```

Comment: "if the user quits their chrome browser while selenium is running the program freezes for a second" -- Yes correct, if you closed the browser manually then selenium look for the browser instance and throws the error message. So do you want to kill the chrome driver instance after you closed it manually?

Comment: yes, if the user by some chance closing chrome, I want to kill the chromedriver.

Comment: Open command prompt and execute this command `taskkill /F /IM ChromeDriver.exe` It will kill all the process of chrome driver. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this require a `try catch` statement? Since the code would have to realize that chrome was closed it would have to catch the error and then execute that command?

Comment: Not required. You can execute this command at end of your suite. Please let me know if it helps I can post an answer with code.

Comment: I have a possible solution, but without seeing any code that you have I cannot post an answer. Please [edit] your question to include the code used to at least initialize ChromeDriver.

Comment: Greg, I updated the question with my code where I initialize the ChromeDriver and also added opening a URL. If you need more, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to discourage the user from closing the browser by running the tests in headless mode. I wouldn't have thought you would want manual intervention in your automated tests.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
```

Comment: The issue with doing headless is the website has a captcha.